# Python POST error 500, only with Windows 7 and file bigger than 1Mb

Tags: python, windows, post, size

I'm using Python 2.7 to Post some data to a server: while this works in Linux and OS X, in Windows it keep uploading for over 4 minutes
and then give up with a "**Error 500**".
But ONLY if file > 1Mb.
On server side the error is generated due to a corrupted file transmission.
I've tried also Python 2.5, to run it in either a Virtual Machine and in two different native Windows environments.
Windows version is Win7 x64.

1. Works with files **<1Mb**
2. Works with **any file size** under OS X and Linux (Ubuntu)
3. If I upload the same file through web interface, or linux or os/x **it works** perfectly, so the problem seems not to be the file itself.

CODE:

```
data = {
    'title': title,
    'file': open(filename),
    'filename': filename
}

datamulti, headers = multipart_encode(data)
request = urllib2.Request(url, datamulti, headers)
print(result.read())
```

Comment: Are you using a framework? Django gives great explanations for why internal error 500 happens.

Comment: Yes on server side they're using Django. They said me that the error is generated because the file sent is not valid (I'm sending zip or obj files).

Comment: what is the error message that Django provides?

Comment: do you see / can you intercept the request headers, as the server sees them?

Comment: Sorry for I'm writing so late: the answer is no, I couldn't intercept those packets. I wish to thank Dietrich for his solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
data = {
    'title': title,
    'file': open(filename, 'rb'),
    'filename': filename
}
```

This will make it so the file is opened in binary mode instead of text mode.

Comment: It was indeed that. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version, tested in win32:

```
    data = {
    'title': title,
    'file': open(filename, 'rb'),
    'filename': filename
    }

    datamulti, headers = multipart_encode(data)
    request = urllib2.Request(url, datamulti, headers, None, True)
    print urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```